# res.format not selecting default properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am posting a request with the `accept` header as `"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"`

However, the response always goes to HTML instead of default, despite this header. Am I missing something here? Since the header isn't HTML, the response should pick the default as that's the only other option.

My code looks like:

```
res.format({
    html: () => {
        res.status(jsonRes.code).send(jsonRes.msg)
    },
    default: () => {
        res.status(jsonRes.code).send(jsonRes)
    }
})
```

Found a solution but not this doesn't correct my misunderstanding of what's going on so I will not be posting it as an answer. This successfully send the JSON formatted response as expected given the same header.

```
res.format({
    html: () => {
        res.status(jsonRes.code).send(jsonRes.msg)
    },
    json: () => {
        res.status(jsonRes.code).send(jsonRes)
    },
    default: () => {
        res.status(jsonRes.code).send(jsonRes)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify why your edit is working, and why you really should answer with an 406 in default:

The Accept HTTP-header field doesn't only tell about one accepted format, but on many. And it also says something about the more preferred ones by ordering these.

From your example the client says something like this: I want json (`application/json`), if you don't have that, give me javascript (`text/javascript`), or *give me anything you can give me* (`*/*`), but with very low preference level (`;q=0.01`).

Your server now parses this request, and comes up with the solution that can not serve `application/json` or `text/javascript`, but can fulfill the `*/*` with its `html` (because `html` also is `*/*`, and still more specific than nothing, or  something we cannot accept).

The Accept field is more like a negotiation between the client and the server, the default case is just there if no solution from the express side can be fulfilled.

The `default` argument is to answer clients that, for example only can parse YAML (Accept set to `text/vnd.yaml, text/x-yaml, text/yaml, application/x-yaml`, but *no* `*/*`), to tell them that there is no YAML available and you should respond with a '406 - Not acceptable` in that case… (Maybe you also log that someone wanted yaml and you didn't give it to them).

[Obligatory link to the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1)

Comment: One upvote for such a great answer and explanation !!! I am sure that I learnt a great things from you. Thank you for your contribution !!!! 1 Upvote !!!